What are the namas for alleviating Ketu effects according to scriptures?
I have learned that Ketu Graha can have challenging effects on one’s life.
Japa is said to be capable of alleviating any malefic effects on an individual. I am specifically looking for the namas suggested in Hindu scriptures to alleviate or reduce the effects of Ketu graha. I am not asking for the general names; the focus should be on Ketu only.
Can anyone provide the namas recommended for japa that are effective in removing the malefic effects of Ketu?

You can chant Om Kem Ketave Namah (ॐ कें केतवे नमः). There are various names and mantras associated with Ketu, but some may require guidance from a guru.
If you’re just starting out, I recommend beginning with the basics. As you progress, the advanced paths will become clearer to you automatically once you are ready.
Additionally, it's worth noting that Lord Ganesha is also associated with Ketu. If you have a connection with Ganesha, consider using his mantra instead.

Yes, since mantras require initiation, I am asking for a nama that anyone is eligible to chant.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
